# Efficiently query 360 days, 720 days, 1080 days and other similar time data from today?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find out the date 360 times from today. How to use SQL Server to implement it efficiently?

If today is May 13, 2021. Then I need to get dates like May 18, 2020, May 24, 2019, May 29, 2018, etc. The difference between these dates and today is a multiple of 360.

My current query is:

```
select *
from table
where dateDIFF(dd,effective_time,#{today}) in (360,720,1080,1440....)
```

New addition:

And I hope this query can conform to SARGable expression.

At present, we need to support the multiple time to the top ten 360.
If there is a query format that can support any 360 times of time and conform to SARGable expression. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql

Comment: If you move the calculation to the right-hand-side then it only has to be done once instead of for every row. (There will of course be a calculation for each multiple of 360, but each only done once.)

Comment: What is the data type for column `effective_time`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes. In fact, its exact type is datetime

Comment: @Martheen Thanks, I will try it now, I think this should help me. Thank you

Comment: @ttttt In that case, is the time part set to zero?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, all the time is valid data, there is no data set to zero.

Comment: Provided OP wants an efficient execution plan, `(id % 10) = 0` ,etc is not a SARGable expression

Comment: @Serg Yes, this is what I worry about. Are there any more efficient queries?

Comment: Yes. Too long for a comment, sorry.

Comment: @Serg Thank you for your help. So what is the query that meets sargable expression under this condition?

Comment: It should in a form  `.. effective_time = dateadd(dd, n, @startDatetime)`

Comment: If you need to get multiple dates then you want to join on a `VALUES` table like `JOIN (VALUES (DATEADD(...)), (DATEADD(...)), (DATEADD(...)) ) v(date) ON v.date = t.effective_time`

Comment: @Serg That might help. But I need to find out more than one effect with different values_ time 。 It seems that the format of DateAdd (DD, N, @ startdatetime) can only find the same value. For example, on May 13, 2021, I need to write effective_ time  = dateadd(dd, -360, '2021-05-13') 。

Comment: @Charlieface This seems to work and conform to SARGable expression. Let me try. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The query can take advantage of an index on `effective_time` column when `effective_time` is not a part of an expression in a condition. For example

```
with nmbrs (n) as (
    select 360  union all
    select 720  union all
    select 1080 union all
    select 1440 
),
dates as (
    select dateAdd(dd, n, @start) dt
    from nmbrs
)   
select t.* 
from table t
join dates d on t.effective_time = d.dt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. And the format is more concise.

Comment: You may wish to accept the answer to show others it is a solution.

Comment: To handle time-of-day in `effective_time` don't you need `... on t.effective_time >= d.dt and t.effective_time < DateAdd( day, 1, d.dt );`?

Comment: @HABO, it's quite possible but it doesn't follow directly from OP query version and wording.

Answer (score 0):

For a sargable expression, you would use:

```
where effective_time in (dateadd(day, 360, convert(date, getdate())),
                         dateadd(day, 720, convert(date, getdate())),
                         dateadd(day, 1080, convert(date, getdate())),
                         dateadd(day, 1440, convert(date, getdate()))
                        )
```

Note:  If `effective_time` has a time component, you will need `convert(date, effective_time)`.  SQL Server can still use an index with this expression.

Comment: How many times does this need to be mentioned? It is sargable but it still [might not be a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: @SMor . . . It is a much better idea than using `datediff()`.

Answer (score 0):

@Serg's answer can be made more concise, by using a `VALUES` clause

```sql
with dates as (
    select dateAdd(dd, n, @start) dt
    from (values (360), (720), (1080), (1440)) nmbrs(n)
)   
select t.* 
from table t
join dates d on t.effective_time = d.dt;
```

If, for example, you also wanted to filter how many rows based on another column, you could add a join condition:

```sql
with dates as (
    select n,
        dateAdd(dd, n, @start) dt
    from (values (360), (720), (1080), (1440)) nmbrs(n)
)   
select t.* 
from table t
join dates d on t.effective_time = d.dt and d.n > t.max_dates;
```